# Ember.Checkbox not working as expected after outer #if statement removed

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, ember.js

I wrote code a couple months back to show a collection of `Ember.Checkbox`es when a user clicks a button. The checkboxes correspond to a collection of other users the user is able to select. There is a simple `#if` block in my template that toggles between showing which users are checked in plain text and the checkboxes that allow the user to select or deselect them. The UI for this looks like:

State 1: Showing the name of the users currently selected.
[image: Showing text users]

State 2: Showing the collection of checkboxes to select after the user has clicked the button. 
[image]

The relevant code for all of this:

_subtaskPartial.handlebars:

```
 <div class="form-group col-lg-10">
  {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="title" placeholder="Title" required="true" class="form-control"}}
</div>
<div class="form-group col-lg-10">
  <label for="subtask-due-date" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Due Date:</label>
  <div id="new-task-date" class="datepicker input-append date col-lg-2" data-date-format="mm/dd/yyyy"> 
    {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="date" class="form-control" size="40"}}
    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
  </div>
  <label for="subtask-users" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Assigned to:</label>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" {{action toggleUserSelect}} {{bind-attr class="isShowingUsers:hide"}}><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user">Select</button>
  {{#if isShowingUsers}}
  <div class="select-users-container">
    <ul id="select-users-list">
      {{#each student in controllers.requiredTasks.selectableStudents}}
        {{render "userCheckbox" student}}
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </div>
  {{else}}
    {{#each student in controller.content.students}}
      {{student.fullName}}
    {{/each}}
  {{/if}}
</div>
```

userCheckbox.handlebars:

```
{{view Ember.Checkbox checkedBinding="userChecked" class="user-select-checkbox"}}
{{fullName}}
```

user_checkbox_controller.js

```
Sis.UserCheckboxController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  userChecked: function(key, value) {
    var content = this.get('content'),
        students = this.get('target.content.students');

    // If the checkbox is checked then add the student (content) to the subtasks
    // associated students
    if (value === true) {
      students.addObject(content);
    } else if (value === false) {
      // Is the checkbox gets unchecked then remove the student from the subtask
      students.removeObject(content);
    }

    // The checkbox should be checked if the subtasks associated students 
    // includes this student. 
    return students.any(function(student, idx){
      return student.id === content.id;
    });
  }.property('target.content.students'),
});
```

abstract_subtask_controller.js (relevant controller code for _subtaskPartial):

```
Sis.AbstractSubtaskController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: ['requiredTasks'],
  isShowingUsers: false,
  date: function(key, value) {
    if (value !== undefined) {
      this.set('content.dueDate', moment(value).toDate());
    }
    if (this.get('content.dueDate')) {
      return moment(this.get('content.dueDate')).format('L');
    } else {
      var newDate = new Date();
      this.set('content.dueDate', newDate);
      return moment(newDate).format('L');
    }
  }.property('content.dueDate'),
  userCanSave: function() {
    var hasAssignedStudents = this.get('content.students.length') >= 1;
    var hasTitle = this.get('content.title') !== undefined && this.get('content.title') !== '';
    return hasAssignedStudents && hasTitle;
  }.property('content.students.length', 'content.title'),
  actions: {
    toggleUserSelect: function() {
      var controller = this;
      controller.toggleProperty('isShowingUsers');
      if (controller.get('isShowingUsers')) {
        Ember.run.next(this, function() {
          // Setup the click handler to set isShowingUsers to false
          $('body').one('click', function() {
            controller.toggleProperty('isShowingUsers');
          });
          // Make sure the select-users-container doesn't trigger the above event
          $(".select-users-container").click(function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            return true;
          });
        });
      }
    },
  }
});
```

Now all of that works as expected, no issues. My designers decided we don't need the 'Select' button as it's just an extra step that really isn't needed, so they asked me to take it out. I would have assumed that this would be really simple. All I should have to do is remove the button, `#if` statement, and else clause in my `_subtaskPartial` and everything should be fine. So I did that like so:

updated _subtaskPartial.js:

```
{{!-- above code removed for brevity --}}
<label for="subtask-users" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Assigned to:</label>
<div class="select-users-container">
  <ul id="select-users-list">
    {{#each student in controllers.requiredTasks.selectableStudents}}
      {{render "userCheckbox" student}}
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</div>
```

Doing the above has somehow broken something and I've been battling against it for a few hours now. I'm not sure what the underlying issue is but whenever I click one of the checkboxes it calls the `userChecked` property which works as normal, but regardless of what it returns it doesn't change the checked state of the `Ember.Checkbox`. This is really confusing to me as all I've done is remove surrounding code in a different template. I've tried various other approaches, but I keep doing '`git stash`' as I'm getting no where.

Somebody mind pushing me in the right direction? Even if it's a better way I can implement a collection of Checkboxes.

Comment: Not that I'd recommend this, but for test sake have you attempted `{{#unless asdfasdfsdfsdf}}checkboxstuff{{/unless}}`  I'm intrigued by the idea that the if was changing the scope.  What version of Ember were you using, a few pull requests for nested if problems have gotten into the latest releases

Comment: Can you post a fiddle : I am not able to replicate the scenario

Comment: @kingpin2k I tried wrapping the code in an #unless, but it didn't change anything. theCoder I'll try putting a fiddle together now, but I think kingpin is right and it's an issue with nested scope or something. We'll see if I can reproduce it.

Comment: I can't seem to put a useful fiddle together. This is a pretty deeply nested controller/handlebars template and even if I spend another hour trying to get something useful, I'm not sure it's going to replicate my problem because it might be the nesting that is causing the issue. Not exactly sure what to do here... Any other debugging tips would be much appreciated.

Comment: And this just got weirder. When I hold down my Mac's 'command' key the checkboxes work as expected. How could something cause the checkboxes to not change value/respond until I held down a certain key??

Comment: Ah finally figured out what was going on. Answering my own question below, thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out this was an issue with having an ember action on an ancestor dom element, causing the checkboxes to behave very strangely.

To fix this issue I had to do change an ancestor action helper from:

`{{action "editTask" on="click"}}`

to this:

`{{action "editTask" on="click" preventDefault=false}}`

If this is happening to you, you can find more info on the preventDefault attribute in [this PR](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/3855).